# Android gradle: Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.material3:material3 using BOM from lib.versions.toml

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an android (compose) projet with a single libs.versions.toml for versions catalog.

In this .toml, I declare a compose BOM and some librairies as follow:

```ini
[versions]
ksp = "1.9.10-1.0.13"
...
androidxComposeBom = "2023.10.01"

[libraries]
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "androidxComposeBom" }
androidx-compose-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
...
androidx-compose-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3"}
androidx-compose-material3-windowSizeClass = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3-window-size-class" }
```

When I do this, I get an error on '**Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.material3:material3**' and '**Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class**'.

I only get an error on material3 libs, not 'ui' or others that have their versions in the BOM

if I specify a version as follow, it works:

```ini
[versions]
material3VersionHack = "1.1.2"

[libraries]
androidx-compose-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3", version.ref = "material3VersionHack"}
```

BUT that defeat the purpose of the BOM: avoid specifying each version...

according to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping the material3 is defined with a *1.1.2* version for BOM *2023.10.01* so what?

=> Why do I need to specify the version manually for material3? is there a way to rely on version defined by the current BOM?

Comment: When you use BOM you done need to specify the version if you really wanted to override the version then and then only you have to define the version manually otherwise it will automatically select version

Comment: @ChiragThummar I agree with you, and in this case, V1.1.2 is the version specified in the BOM so I should not need to override it manually. And more than that: when I will update the BOM, I don't want to update material3 manually (or forget it)... but without specifying the version, I get the error and that is all the point of the question: why? :-)